# Stack Exchange is in violation of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license agreement

Tags: support

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Does software engineering in C derive a new insight into the halting problem?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/441076/does-software-engineering-in-c-derive-a-new-insight-into-the-halting-problem)

## Unless my deleted and locked posts are unlocked so that I can add my copyright notice SE is in violation of the "attribution" portion of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license agreement.

[**Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International Public License**](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode)

> Section 3 – License Conditions.
>
> Your exercise of the Licensed Rights is expressly  made subject to the
> following conditions.
>
> a. Attribution.
>
> ```
> 1. If You Share the Licensed Material 
>    (including in modified form), You must:
>
>   A. retain the following if it is supplied by 
>      the Licensor with the Licensed Material:
>
>      i. identification of the creator(s) of the 
>         Licensed Material and any others designated 
>         to receive attribution, in any reasonable manner 
>         requested by the Licensor (including by pseudonym 
>         if designated);
>
>     ii. a copyright notice;
> ```

**Please unlock all of my deleted posts so that I can add my copyright notice.**

Comment: [You almost certainly cannot revoke your license grant](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/are-licenses-irrevocable-by-default). IANAL.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I never granted anyone a license to block my access to my own work.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not required to display your content, just as you have no right to shout "fire" in a crowded theatre.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Unless my deleted and locked posts are unlocked so that I can add my copyright notice SE is in violation of the "attribution" portion of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license agreement.

Comment: I suggest you will need to take this up with Stack Exchange directly; use the "Contact" link at the bottom of every page because the consensus of the community is that you are completely, totally and utterly wrong.

Comment: @PhilipKendall CC BY-SA 4.0 has an attribution requirement. The attribution is lost when an account is deleted. This puts SE in breach of the license agreement.

Comment: I recommend to check https://meta.stackexchange.com on this topic, for example, this question: [Licensing question: Should Stack Exchange delete all my questions and answers when my account gets closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333910/licensing-question-should-stack-exchange-delete-all-my-questions-and-answers-wh). And it would be really polite if you stop overusage of use bold face and larger fonts, your posts read like you are screaming loudly, and that makes me stop listening.

Comment: @DocBrown Not a single person on any group anywhere has given me a fair and accurate review out of thousands of reviews on many different forums over the last 12 months. Everyone starts with the fundamental assumption that I must be wrong and only reviews my work within the boundary of that assumption. **When these reviews even totally ignore verified facts** then we are at the stage where screaming is totally appropriate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it should be asked on Meta.Stackexchange, not here (but I recommend to scan through existing questions if there isn't already a Q&A which answers the issue).

Comment: @DocBrown that should be added as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

That's not how things work.

You already own the copyright for all your posts. You do not need any particular notices for this.

You have granted Stack Exchange an *irrevocable* license under the CC-BY-SA terms to host your content. And Stack Exchange does clearly attribute you as the author of your content, which seems to comply with the CC-BY-SA conditions. If you want to be attributed under a particular name, you can update your username.

The people who read and answer these meta posts are community members and do not represent Stack Exchange. If you believe that your content being hosted here violates your copyright, you can send Stack Exchange an actual notice, as explained in the [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#copyright). They provide contact details for their legal team.

Comment: When my account is deleted by me or others I lose the attribution of my work to me, thus effectively lose my copyright.

Comment: @polcott, the presence, lack or form of an attribution does not in any way affect the fact that you own the copyrights of your posts. That fact stems from the rights granted to you in copyright law (and the fact that the TOS of SE does not require a transfer of rights). Attributions are only an aid in establishing who is the holder of the copyrights.

Comment: If for any reason my account is deleted this would put SE in breach of the attribution requirement of the CC-BY-SA license agreement. As I have already indicated by my direct quote of this license that fact that my copyright notice is missing is already a breach.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau "the presence, lack or form of an attribution does not in any way affect the fact that you own the copyrights of your posts." **It does put SE in breach of the "attribution" aspect of the CC-BY-SA license agreement.  (see above quoted license)**